# Variable "iii" declared as a counter in for loop not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, naming-conventions, adobe-illustrator

TL;DR version: is there any reason a variable name of "iii" wouldn't work as expected when used as a counter in a for loop?

Longer, funnier version: I'm writing some javascript to iterate through layers and pageItems in Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 and do stuff with them. In my third nested For loop, I used a variable named "iii" as a counter like so:

```
for(var iii = 0; iii < curItem.pageItems.length -1; iii++){
//try to do stuff with curItem.pageItems[iii], get "undefined"
}
```

I spent a long while trying to figure out what was wrong with the logic and kept coming up with nothing. I went through it with a colleague line-by-line, desperate, hoping he (or even I) might notice something trivial that I might have overlooked (he's not a much of a programmer but understands bits and pieces). He asks me why I named my counters "i", "ii", and "iii". I said I saw someone use "ii" recently for a nested for loop and thought "that's kinda neat, it's short and quickly communicates the nesting level of the loop!" I tell him that it doesn't matter, "iii" is a valid variable name. He convinces me to humour him so I replace the "iii" to "p" and the code proceeds to work. Change it back to "iii" and it fails. *blink* I am in shock at the amount of humble pie I'm going to have to eat for years to come as he will inevitably bring this up at every opportunity.

So yeah, what am I missing here? Does this make any sense at all? Thanks!

Comment: Provide a working example.

Comment: What JS engine are you using?  If I do exactly what you described in Chrome, somearray[iii] inside the loop works just fine.

Comment: a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uwqvsppu/1/

Comment: Yeah I tested it outside of AI and it worked as expected for me too. I was kinda thinking it had something to do with Illustrator... though I get that's probably a more niche thing around here. I know it's running an older version of ECMA because I couldn't make use of indexOf. Having trouble finding an answer on Google... I'll grab a copy of the code when I'm at work tomorrow so I can give more info.

Comment: [Indirectly related] I don't know Adobe Illustrator or how the array indexes go in it, but aren't you missing one element by doing `length - 1`? It looks like you will never process the last element in `curItem.pageItems`

Comment: It may depend on what exactly stuff you're doing inside the loop. The often cause of such error is if you change the array (its length) inside the loop. In these cases you need to iterate your array backward: `for (for(var iii = curItem.pageItems.length-1; i>0; iii--)`